# SQL Server Trigger on INSERT always ROLLED BACK

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a trigger that will not allow to past a client out from `USA`.

So my code is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER location_tr 
ON t1 FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @country VARCHAR(50)

    SET @country = (SELECT country FROM inserted);

    IF @country <> 'USA'
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'You cant add user out of USA!'

        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
    ELSE
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

So now, I can't do any `UPDATE` or `INSERT` on the table t1.

I guess I'm going wrong with a `COMMIT/ROLLBACK` commands. Need help. Thanks

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `UPDATE` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` and `Deleted` will each contain 25 rows. WHich of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT country FROM inserted` - it's non-deterministic - you'll get one, and ignore all others. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: Instead of a trigger, you could use a constraint to prevent countries from being set to non-USA values; should be more efficient if it's suitable for your requirement.

Comment: Also - the trigger runs in the context of the transaction - if everything is OK - you don't need to do *anything* - definitely don't call `COMMIT` in your trigger!

Comment: It's unnecessary to explicitly commit the transaction as well

Comment: By the time this trigger fires, the data will already have been written to the table so rolling back won't roll back the user you're attempting to keep from being added.  With a trigger your only option would be to use an INSTEAD OF.  Keep in mind if anything goes awry any attempt to write would be lost.  You're best to handle the insert of a user via a procedure so you can prevent writing of data if someone is not in the USA.  This will also get around the non deterministic part @marc_s mentioned since you will be forced to only work one row at a time.

Comment: @user3727926: you're **wrong** - the trigger runs in the (transaction) context of the `INSERT` or `UPDATE` being performed, and if you want to stop an operation, you **CAN** do that be using `ROLLBACK` - this **WILL** rollback the whole operation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue is that your trigger does not support multiple rows. You should use EXISTS instead of setting the value of a variable. Something along these lines.

```
CREATE TRIGGER location_tr ON t1
FOR INSERT, UPDATE AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(select * from inserted where Country <> 'USA')
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'You cant add user out of USA!'
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        END    
END
```

Comment: But again: you should not call `COMMIT` inside your trigger. If you want to abort the operation - use `ROLLBACK`; if everything is ok - just don't do anything....

Comment: Agreed 100% @marc_s. I didn't even look at commit, just fixed the glaring issue. Will update momentarily.